# Python 3.4 opencv import error

Tags: python, opencv

I've tried the installation of opencv 3 for Python 3+ on the Raspberry Pi. After  importing the opencv using `import cv2` on Python shell it gives me this error:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_cv3)
```

What could be the possible problem / solution?

Answer (score -2):

I have googled for a bit. I found this wonderful, super duper easy [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/). Try it out and if it works, accept my answer.

Comment: In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.